# Google Trends: What difference of the buttons "Top" and "Rising"

Tags: google-trends

https://www.google.com/trends/explore#cmpt=q

I can't understand, what is:
What difference of the buttons "Top" and "Rising". What queries in this pages?
What do the numbers(100, 40) mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about code you've written

Comment: he is new so give him time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

top: what has been at top overall. Rising: what is becoming popular. **Example:**

desktop usage has been on top.

however, cell phone use is rising and is popular (rising more than everything else even computers)

top is average of some long time...where recent acceleration is what recently popular or rising means.